# How to get column index of header column in AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex

I want to know column index of header in `AdvancedDataGrid` when a user clicks on header - either left click or right click.

Comment: In advance of what? And learn 2 accept answers you are getting on your questions ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AdvancedDataGrid` dispatches a `headerRelease` event when you click on its header. This event has a zero based [columnIndex](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/events/AdvancedDataGridEvent.html#columnIndex) property.

There is one problem though: The `headerRelease` event is dispatched only if the [clicked column is sortable and the data provider supports sorting](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGridBaseEx.html#event:headerRelease).

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid headerRelease="handleHeaderClick(event)">
  <!-- Columns and stuff -->
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
<mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

    private function handleHeaderClick(event:AdvancedDataGridEvent):void
    {
      var index:Number = event.columnIndex;
    }

  ]]>
</mx:Script>
```